# increase size of pop up closeicon react js antd

Tags: reactjs, antd

im using react js antd and need to chart expanded with clicking. how do i increase the size of X button of popup visual.

[image]

```
        <Modal
            title="Sales"
            visible={isModalOpen}
            width="95%"
            style={{ top: "20px" }}
            bodyStyle={{ height: "calc(100vh - 170px)" }}
            onCancel={handleCancel}
            footer={null}
            // closeIcon={{ height: "2em", width: "2em" }}
        >
```

i have added **closeIcon** and set width and heigt but it didn't work.

Comment: `closeIcon={icon here}`

Comment: Can't i increase the existing X button size without using other icons?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a specific Icon with `closeIcon` and specify the style there:

```
<Modal
  visible={visible}
  title={"Neues Item hinzufügen"}
  cancelText="Abbrechen"
  okText={"Speichern"}
  maskClosable={false}
  onCancel={onClose}
  onOk={form.submit} 
  forceRender
  closeIcon={<CloseOutlined style={{fontSize: "30px", color: "#000000"}}/>}
>
```

[image]